MPAndroidChart - LineChart has wired behavior
I am using MPAndroidChart, and my chart is placed inside a BottomSheetDialogFragment. Sometimes when I open the bottomSheet, the entire chart appears strange. However, when I switch to a different date range and then switch back(the chart will redraw), then the chart becomes normal. Has anyone encountered this problem?
wired behavior
(https://i.sstatic.net/YjqZK1Ex.png)
After switch to 90d and back to 30d in data range tab, it becomes normal
(https://i.sstatic.net/9QJ1G04K.png)
only happened to some device

Please include a minimum complete example that reproduces the issue. Without that, nobody is going to be able to help.
